# Convert all strings to lowercase in a scala code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, string, scala

Do we have a functionality in Eclipse such that all the strings in a code can be converted to their respective lowercases?
I sound like a really lazy programmer but it would be awesome to have one of these available.
For example: All my pattern matches change from

```
       case ("TriParty Repo::GIC Concentrations" |
      "TriParty Repo::GIC Sector Concentrations" |
      "TriParty Repo::GIC Industry Group Concentrations" |
      "TriParty Repo::GIC Industry Concentrations")
```

to

```
       case ("triparty repo::gic concentrations" |
      "triparty repo::gic sector concentrations" |
      "triparty repo::gic industry group concentrations" |
      "triparty repo::gic industry concentrations")
```

if yes, can this be extended to an entire project?

Answer (score 0):

Do a block select and:

- To lower case: CTRL+SHIFT+Y
- To UPPER case: CTRL+SHIFT+X

Comment: how do you do the block select?

Comment: This changes everything within that block to lowercase. I only want the strings to convert to lowercase

Comment: I see, for really-really lazy programmers, you'll have to write a script, which is not-so-lazy after all. Some regex magic should get this done quickly.